#  Convert small vbscript xmlhttp to php?

Tags: php, vbscript

I have a very simple xmlhttp snippet that i need to convert to php. I have absolutly 0 experience in php, so i was hoping someone could lend me a hand.

Here is the VBScript code:

```
dim xmlhttp 
set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "GET","http://myurl.com/return.aspx?d=" & Request.QueryString("d"), false  
xmlhttp.send
Response.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=windows-1252"
Response.Write xmlhttp.responsetext
Set xmlhttp = nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=windows-1252');
echo $result = file_get_contents("http://myurl.com/return.aspx?d=".$_GET["d"]);
```

for CURL alternative:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=windows-1252');
$c = curl_init("http://myurl.com/return.aspx?d=".$_GET["d"]);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $result = curl_Exec($c);
```

Comment: It turns out that file_get_contents is disabled on the server, and it is recommended that i use "curl" instead - aprreantly because of security issues? I tried simply to replace "file_get_contents" with "curl_init" but that does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutly 0 experience in vbscript but i think what you do is to fetch a specific URL?

Here is how this is done in php:

```
<?php
$r = new HttpRequest('http://example.com/feed.rss', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r->setOptions(array('lastmodified' => filemtime('local.rss')));
$r->addQueryData(array('category' => 3));
try {
    $r->send();
    if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200) {
        file_put_contents('local.rss', $r->getResponseBody());
        header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=windows-1252');
        echo $r->getResponseBody();
    }
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
?>
```

Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=windows-1252');
echo file_get_contents('http://myurl.com/return.aspx?d=' . $_GET['d']);
```